# How do I split a String by pixels

Tags: java, string, split

[image]

The string in the picture is over 570 pixels (I know this because I used FontMetrics to get it), though I checked the java documentation, String doesn't appear to have a method that lets you splice a string if it's over x pixels.

Comment: I guess you have to write yourself a litter helper method :P I did so myself in a 2D Game I wrote for NPC dialogues, it's really not difficult and there are different approaches.

Comment: It's right that there is no "easy" out-of-the-box solution for this. But if you wrote more clearly what you want to achive, there might be further hints possible. For example, one can sometimes use a `JLabel` with HTML content as a "renderer" for formatted strings (where the line-break is done automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep cutting the last character from the string until it fits.

```
String initialString = "1234567890";
String firstPart = initialString;
while (metrics.stringWidth(firstPart) > MAX_WIDTH) {
    firstPart = firstPart.substring(0, firstPart.length() - 1);
}
String secondPart = initialString.substring(firstPart.length(), initialString.length());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm going to try this. If it works, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Awesome, it works, though how can I get the second half so I can output it to a the first line, without this my problem wouldn't be fixed. Actually NVM, I just minused it by the difference, thanks for ALL the help, I accepted your answer

Comment: Awesome thanks again, I am going to take some time to master strings, because I never knew about substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are objects in Java and do not have any representation of how they are processed in terms of pixels on screen. There is no way to use the String object itself to do what it is you want to do (unless you implement your own methods).

You need to check your method for "printing" your String to screen, and modifying that method so that the string does not get over 570 px long.

Let's say you have a method that prints text:

```
text(myText, width, height);
```

Here you would set the width to 570.

Comment: Yeah, I need to know how to modify it to make sure it doesn't go over 570 px, because I need to end the String before any characters pass 570 px.

Comment: Well, let us see some code, that would make it easier to give you a more specific answer. As it is now I can only give you some generic answer that makes you think of a solution yourself.

Comment: This is my code to print out a message: http://pastebin.com/LyNrZsq6 I basically get the width of the player's username and message, then I output it (for debug purposes). Then I append it to an ArrayList which then my render method keeps checking over to see if there are new messages, then printing them out with Graphics.